# VueJS: How can I edit all components of the same type in App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have a template as such with FruitPrices as a component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <span @click=SOME_FUNCTION> Change currency </span>
      <FruitPrices fruit="apple"></FruitPrices>
      <FruitPrices fruit="banana"></FruitPrices>
      <FruitPrices fruit="orange"></FruitPrices>
             ...
             ....
             .....
</template>
...
...
...
import FruitPrices from ./component/FruitPrices.vue
```

I was wondering would it be possible to have SOME_FUNCTION be a method that alters the currency across all the FruitPrices Components? i.e. if some components are in USD, some are in GBP, can I set them all to Euros via a method in the current main App.?

Comment: what is the FruitPrices component?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a property in the data object for currency and use that across all components and have a function alter it.

```
data() {
  return {
    currency: "USD",
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  changeCurrency(newCurrency){
    this.currency = newCurrency;
  }
}
```

and in the template

```
<span @click=changeCurrency('Euro')> Change currency </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got the logic of your problem but maybe you can use the vue **props** like this:

```
      <FruitPrices fruit="apple" :currency="newCurrency || 'USD'"></FruitPrices>
      <FruitPrices fruit="banana" :currency="newCurrency || 'GBP'"></FruitPrices>
      <FruitPrices fruit="orange" :currency="newCurrency || 'USD'"></FruitPrices>
```

you can define the props `currency` inside the component `FruitPrices`. If the `currency` prop is not defined then the second currency is going to be taken as default (for example `"newCurrency || 'GBP'"` if `newCurrency` is null then the currency GBP is taken as default).

Vue docs for props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Then in the main template component, you define the variable `newCurrency` and you pass that variable to the prop `currency` of the component `FruitPrices`:

```
data: () => {
    newCurrency: null
},
methods: {
    setNewCurrency() {
        this.newCurrency = this.someFieldOfYourForm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this component to pass the currency, price and fruit to each component FruitPrices component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- USD is selected by default, once the option change, the prices will be updated -->
    <select v-model="currency">
      <!-- allows to select one currency at time, it shows all the currencies
          that exist in the currencies array data property -->
      <option
        v-for="(currencyOption, index) in currencies"
        :key="index"
        :value="currencyOption"
      >
        <!-- show only the currency name as option -->
        {{ currencyOption.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <div v-for="(fruit, fruitIndex) in fruitsWithPrices" :key="fruitIndex">
      <!-- if everything is working fine, you don't need close tags for empty
          custom component, you can use '/' at the end of the first tag to self close it-->
      <FruitPrices :name="fruit.name" :convertedPrice="fruit.convertedPrice" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import FruitPrices from '../somePlace/FruitPrices'
export default {
  name: "FruitPricesContainer",
  components: { FruitPrices },
  data: () => ({
    fruits: [
      {
        name: 'Apple',
        price: 0.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Banana',
        price: 0.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        price: 0.25
      }
    ],
    currency: {
      // Base currency, exchangeRate = 1
      exchangeRate: 1,
      name: 'USD'
    },
    // Used exchange rates only for demo purpose, not are the real and valid exchange rates
    currencies: [
      {
        exchangeRate: 1,
        name: 'USD'
      },
      {
        exchangeRate: 1.2,
        name: 'EUR'
      },
      {
        exchangeRate: 0.7,
        name: 'SGD'
      },
      {
        exchangeRate: 700,
        name: 'MXN'
      },
      {
        exchangeRate: 3700,
        name: 'COP'
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    // The fruitsWithPrices listen for changes in both, the fruit and
    // the currency, so once you change it by selecting a different currency
    // the prices will be updated automatically (nice)
    fruitsWithPrices() {
      return this.fruits.map((fruit) => {
        return {
          ...fruit, // Add name and original price to the returned object
          convertedPrice: fruit.price * this.currency.exchangeRate // Add the price based on the exchange rate
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, let's create the FruitPrices component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ name }}: {{ convertedPrice }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "FruitPrices",
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    convertedPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And it's ready! (Tbh, I didn't test it, please let me know if you have errors or problems).